# Dialogflow is not detecting the intent with context

Tags: rest, dialogflow-es

I am connecting to Dialogflow REST API v2beta1 to the method: `projects.agent.sessions.detectIntent`. In the first request I send a text and the response is returning the expected result which contains `outputContexts`; when I made the 2nd request I send the context and it should find the intent which is linked to that context, but instead of that it is returning the Default Fallback Intent.

What may be the problem on the 2nd request?

Here are the URL and requests with their respective responses, and below I added the screenshots of the intents expected to match.

**URL**
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/project-name/agent/sessions/12343:detectIntent

**1st request**

```
{
    "queryInput":{
        "text":{
            "text":"play a video about love",
            "languageCode":"en"
        }
    }
}
```

**1st response**

```
{
    "responseId": "15a3b767-52fe-4fc2-8ffd-9d7bb9c6961a",
    "queryResult": {
        "queryText": "play a video about love",
        "action": "video.play",
        "parameters": {
            "organization": "",
            "tag": "Love",
            "item": ""
        },
        "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
        "fulfillmentText": "Here is a video about Love!",
        "fulfillmentMessages": [
            {
                "platform": "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE",
                "simpleResponses": {
                    "simpleResponses": [
                        {
                            "textToSpeech": "Here is a video about Love!"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "text": {
                    "text": [
                        "Here is a video about Love!"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "outputContexts": [
            {
                "name": "projects/project-name/agent/sessions/12343/contexts/play-video",
                "lifespanCount": 5,
                "parameters": {
                    "tag": "Love",
                    "organization": "",
                    "tag.original": "love",
                    "item": "",
                    "organization.original": "",
                    "item.original": ""
                }
            }
        ],
        "intent": {
            "name": "projects/project-name/agent/intents/9e5d2bbc-81f3-4700-8740-01504b05443f",
            "displayName": "video-play"
        },
        "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
        "languageCode": "en"
    }
}
```

**2nd request (where the problem should be)**

```
{
    "queryParams":{
        "contexts":[
            {
                "name":"projects/project-name/agent/sessions/12342/contexts/play-video"
            }
        ]
    },
    "queryInput":{
        "text":{
            "text":"that video matters a lot for me",
            "languageCode":"en"
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd response**

```
{
    "responseId": "40d1f94f-4673-4644-aa53-99c854ff2596",
    "queryResult": {
        "queryText": "that video matters a lot for me",
        "action": "input.unknown",
        "parameters": {},
        "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
        "fulfillmentText": "Can you say that again?",
        "fulfillmentMessages": [
            {
                "text": {
                    "text": [
                        "Sorry, what was that?"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "intent": {
            "name": "projects/project-name/agent/intents/10c88e8d-f16a-4905-b829-f596d3b3c588",
            "displayName": "Default Fallback Intent",
            "isFallback": true
        },
        "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
        "languageCode": "en"
    }
}
```

**Screenshots of the intents expected to match**

1st intent
[image]

2nd intent
[image]

**Useful documentation**

- Doc of the method: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent
- Doc of the Context object: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/Context
- Doc of the Params object to be sent: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/QueryParameters

Comment: Can you update your question to include screen shots of the Intents that you expect to match?

Comment: Hi @Prisoner I added the screenshots, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your second request has an incomplete context. Although you're specifying the `name`, you're not including the `lifespanCount` parameter. Since you're not providing a parameter, it defaults to 0, which means that it has timed out.

You should send back *exactly* what you received from the `outputContext` attribute in the previous reply.

```
{
    "queryParams":{
        "contexts":[
            {
                "name": "projects/project-name/agent/sessions/12343/contexts/play-video",
                "lifespanCount": 5,
                "parameters": {
                    "tag": "Love",
                    "organization": "",
                    "tag.original": "love",
                    "item": "",
                    "organization.original": "",
                    "item.original": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "queryInput":{
        "text":{
            "text":"that video matters a lot for me",
            "languageCode":"en"
        }
    }
}
```